# can't make the context whose type is CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL in Android JNi

Tags: android, opengl-es, opencl

I'm optimizing my app that is FaceDetection Algorithm using OpenCL & OpenGL.OpenGL API was used to make read/write Image. meanwhile, I want to make 1 context with multiple devices(2 device : one is GPU, the other is CPU) for CPU/GPU co-processing. but I can't make CPU device. I expected 'contextProperties for using openGL'.

What shoud I do for using using multiple device with OpenGL??

```
cl_context_properties contextProperties[] = {
        CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) eglGetCurrentContext(),
        CL_EGL_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties) eglGetCurrentDisplay(),
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) firstPlatformId,
        0 };                               // If  CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL is set, program can't execution. 
context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
        NULL, NULL, &errNum);//creating a context for a GPU device,

if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
    LOGE("[LYW]Could not create GPU context, trying CPU...");
    context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties,
            CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, NULL, NULL, &errNum); //creating a context for a CPU device
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
        LOGE("[LYW] Failed to create an OpenCL GPU or CPU context.");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid no Android OpenCL implementation supports CPU. So you cannot do that at the moment. However, I would expect poor speeds, since a mobile is really slow copying data around.

Comment: I don't see the reason why you cannot run OpenCL for CPU. Actually, Qualcomm Adreno 320, 330, 420, all of them support GPU OpenCL. (for 420, only since Android 5.0, the OpenCL on CPU is removed. but with Kitkat, CPU is still supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above OpenCL CPU devices are not supported by any particular vendor on Android. As such, if you have an Android device that does support OpenCL on the GPU, you could used one of the following options to integrate the CPU:

- Use a simple thread pool to manage CPU threads
- Use Qualcomm's MARE tasking runtime*, which provides an integrated view of the  CPU and GPU, including access to OpenCL within a single framework.

Alternatively you could use Renderscript which can provide CPU and GPU support but limited in functionality compared to OpenCL and/or MARE.

- More information on Qualcomm's MARE can be found here: https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/maximize-hardware/parallel-computing-mare

Comment: thanks for your advice. :) I definitely check it now.